# Kendo Mobile ListView not paging

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm using Kendo Mobile ListView, and I have problem with pagination, first page is displayed but after that my ListView seems stuck, i.e. loader appears, but no data is added to my list, also I can see in my debugger that data was pulled from the server. Here is my code:

```
m_userRoutines: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: pub.serverUrl + "api/Statistics/GetAllRoutinesUserHasDone",
                beforeSend: function (req) {
                    //radi uz data type json
                    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + app.loginToken);
                },
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function (e) {
            console.log("user routines loaded", e.response);
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (data) {
                return data;
            },
            total: function (data) {

                return m_userWorkouts.get("workoutsCount");
            }
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found answer, according to Kendo Mobile documentation:

> In order for the scrolling to occur smoothly, the page size should not
>   be too low. For example, if 5 items are visible on the page, at least
>   15 physical DOM elements are needed, which means that the DataSource
>   page size should be 30 or greater.

Problem with my page size is that it was too low, when I set my pageSize to 60 everything worked fine :)